# Elements position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I started to build a classified ads website and I'm encountering some problems along the way. 
On [this](http://mediaheart.ro/new/index.html) webpage, which is the template that I'll use for the site, I'm having some problems with positioning 2 elements that appear out of their place on all browsers except.. IE 7 :)

Firebug tells me nothing cause i tried several tricks to move them at their place but had no success.

What could be the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: IE7? Does that even have 1 percent share?

Comment: Which elements? The two between the input box and blue rectangle?

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks for your intentions and interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```css
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The default `vertical-align` is `baseline`, which is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked! Td's were having `valing="top"` but for nothing.

Comment: i'd rather suggest the removal of the `vertical-align: baseline;` from   `.top` because `td` already has the `vertical-align: top;` property.

Comment: @AndreiR: Well, I was about to agree with you but I don't see anything with a class of `top`. And `document.querySelectorAll('.top')` agrees.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `<tbody>`'s `vertical-align` equal to `top`